# Does PHP provide a cronjob like function?

Tags: php, cron

Is it possible to create recurrent actions with PHP?

I want to execute some statements every day at 10 o'clock. I know this could be done with cronjobs, but I only have a regular webhoster that does **not** provide Unix access.

Comment: What kind of job....if it is an DB job, then you can create an Event in Mysql

Comment: Maybe you can trigger a script (hosted on your webserver) by calling its url from a cronjob on your own machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fire cronjobs without Unix installed on a machine.

http://www.easycron.com/ provides cron services:

> EasyCron is a task scheduler which provides services of calling URLs
>   at specified time or by time interval. Once register with us, you get
>   abilities to:

Some of the features:

- Get Email notice about cron jobs' execution. (Applied to premium
  users)
- Random cron jobs.
- Cron job with cookies supported. (Applied to
  premium users)
- Cron job executed using POST method. (Applied to
  premium users
- View execution logs of each cron job. (Applied to
  premium users)
- Cron job run time predictions. (Applied to premium
  users)
- Manage online cron jobs at your own user panel.
- Set cron job according to the date and time in your own account timezone.

*I am not conntected to this service in any way, but it provided the solution I was looking for.*

Answer (score 2):

No, PHP does not have anything equivalent. PHP in conjunction with a web server is made to execute small scripts for a very short period of time. In order to execute something at a specific time, a PHP script would have to stay running permanently and check what time it is. You *can* do that in PHP, but likely not on a limited web host that optimizes for short-in-parallel scripts.

Lacking the ability to run a permanent script, and lacking any help from the system itself (cron), the only thing you can do is to make a normal web request every day at a specific time to trigger the action. I.e. the timer is on an external system that pokes your system at a specific time. That's an ugly workaround hack. Look for a better host if you want something nicer.